# How do I open an Access .mdb when I don't have permission to convert/enable it?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I want to open an old database, but when I am trying to open it it shows some error. I have the screenshot below

[image]

Comment: The error message is quite informative - did you already check all the possible issues listed?

Comment: @Filburt to be fair, if you were new to Access, how meaningful is the instruction "you must join the workgroup that defines the user accounts used to access the database"?

Comment: @hawbsl Joining a workgroup to obtain windows OS privileges has nothing to do with being new to MS Access. The point is that this question shows zero effort on trying to understand the error and check the possible issues.

Comment: @Filburt oh i thought this message was something to do with the .mdw file (which can be fiddly/confusing) ... my mistake

Comment: Does the database file you are trying to open have a file extension of `.mdb`? Is there another file in the same folder with a file extension of `.mdw`? (Note that the two files need not have the same name.)

Comment: ys it is .mdb and there is .mdw file